# Declaring Target parameter for @Reference Annotation in Apache Felix

Tags: reference, annotations, apache-felix

It defines documentation for felix SCR annotations .
http://felix.apache.org/site/scr-annotations.html#SCRAnnotations-Reference

I want to use , @Reference Annotation and also want to set target service as configurational parameter .

Documentation says  : A service target filter to select specific services to be made available. In order to be able to overwrite the value of this value by a configuration property, this parameter must be declared. If the parameter is not declared, the respective declaration attribute will not be generated

How to declare this parameter .

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but I couldn't find a simple example anywhere either, so this might help somebody else anyway.

For example, to filter DataSource with Felix annotations:

```
@Reference(cardinality = OPTIONAL_UNARY, policy = DYNAMIC, name = "dataSource")
private DataSource dataSource;
```

Generates this XML:

```
<reference name="dataSource" interface="javax.sql.DataSource" cardinality="0..1" policy="dynamic" bind="bindDataSource" unbind="unbindDataSource"/>
```

The property needs **.target** appended to it as per section 112.6 of the [OSGi 4.2 Compendium Spec](http://www.osgi.org/download/r4v42/r4.cmpn.pdf)

So in my configuration I have set the LDAP filter as:

```
dataSource.target = (some.key=some.value)
```

Note: I'm not using un/bind methods, letting DS generate those for me.